# How to make a simple CORS request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, cors, ionic-framework

**THE SITUATION:**

I am making an app in AngularJs.
I need to make a CORS request to fetch data from an api on a different address.

On the api i output a very simple json, for test purpose:

```
[{"id":0,"name":"First"},{"id":1,"name":"Second"},{"id":2,"name":"Third"}]
```

I need to fetch these data and display on my app.

**$HTTP CALL:**

making the $http call i get the following error, because the api is on a different domain:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

**CORS REQUEST - THE CODE:**

```
// Create the XHR object.
$scope.createCORSRequest = function(method, url)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) 
    {
        // XHR for Chrome/Firefox/Opera/Safari.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    } 
    else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") 
    {
        // XDomainRequest for IE.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } 
    else 
    {
        // CORS not supported.
        xhr = null;
    }

    return xhr;
}


// Helper method to parse the title tag from the response.
$scope.getTitle = function(text)
{
    return text.match('<title>(.*)?</title>')[1];
}


// Make the actual CORS request.
$scope.makeCorsRequest = function()
{
    var url = 'http://DOMAIN.COM/main/json_export_test';

    var xhr = $scope.createCORSRequest('GET', url);

    console.log('----- xhr -----');
    console.log(xhr);

    if (!xhr) 
    {
        alert('CORS not supported');
        return;
    }

    // Response handlers.
    xhr.onload = function() 
    {
        var text = xhr.responseText;
        var title = $scope.getTitle(text);
        alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
    };

    xhr.onerror = function() 
    {
        alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
    };

    xhr.send();
}
```

When i run the function makeCorsRequest i get the alert called by xhr.onerror

But i have no clues why it isn't working.

**THE API:**

This is the very simple php function in the api, for test purpose:

```
public function json_export_test()
{
    $data = array(
        array(
            "id" => 0,
            "name" => "First"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "Second"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "Third"
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i make a simple CORS request?

**EDIT - THE SOLUTION:**

This is how it looks the api after having edited it, thanks to the reply:

```
public function json_export_test()
{
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

    $data = array(
        array(
            "id" => 0,
            "name" => "First"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 1,
            "name" => "Second"
        ),
        array(
            "id" => 2,
            "name" => "Third"
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: the server must support CORS headers, otherwise, the browser will deny the response. The server will send the CORS headers in the response if implemented to do it. You add CORS headers in the server is you want your service to be called from a client hosted in a different host that your service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general: You just make a normal request using `XMLHttpRequest`. The browser will handle the rest. (The exception is in old browsers which either don't support CORS or which require you to use `XDomainRequest` instead of `XMLHttpRequest` — but you seem to be accounting for that already).

The error message you are getting indicates that you are not getting a CORS **response**, so the browser doesn't have permission to give the other site's data to your JavaScript.

You need to include `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` (or something more specific) in the HTTP **response** to the cross-origin request.

Comment: Adding to the last comment, setting up the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` cannot be done in the AngularJs request. It must be done on the server processing the response. This means that unless you own the service you're requesting from, CORS is not an option

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can you give please a code example with the proper Access-Control-Allow-Origin:* setup?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio — See the code sample in the last sentence of the answer. (I can't tell you how to configure your server / your server side code to output that header because you haven't even told us what server / programming language you are using there)

Comment: Ok. I have included the simple api test. I have to include the header there?

Comment: That looks vaguely like Java, but there's no clue about how to set HTTP response headers in that code. It's a likely place, but there isn't enough information there for me to tell you how to set it.

Comment: Looks like PHP. `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` Just remember you must set headers before output anything (with echo for example).

Comment: can you give please a simple example how to properly do it?

Comment: @johnnyfittizio — ippi did 5 minutes ago

Comment: You can put it inside your json_export_test()-function, but only if you haven't output anything to the page before that point.